# Sourcetree cannot clone repository if wrong login credential in the first time

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

After I enter the clone url it appears a login screen entering the login name and password.

However, I wonder I type them wrongly, I failed to clone the repository. Then, no matter I retry to clone or even I reinstall Sourcetree, it gives me error when trying to clone:

```
Error: remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed
```

no more login screen comes out but keeps me access denied.

I had go for Credential Manager in Control Panel as [Remove credentials from Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git) tells, but I cannot find any credentials relating to it.

I am new to Sourcetree and Git, hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/How-to-update-HTTP-S-credentials-in-sourcetree/qaq-p/297564

same method, remove the passwd file from

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree
```

then you are able to enter your password again:)